# The Mad Hatter's Picture Book

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Winterbash has arrived once again. I thought it might be nice to have a meta thread to show off everyone's wardrobe.

Bragging is encouraged. Ragging is not.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

This is what classic Spartans think of your silly hats.

> Kidding. Hats are cool :)

Comment: "The Force"? This ... is ... SPARTA!

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Snazzy!

> We're not really sure yet quite what causes this one. My suspicion is that I got it for getting involved in a back-and-forth comment chat with a user.

---

[image]

The stars coming off this one really pull together the whole masquerade-party vibe.

> I believe the "secret" on this one was participating on a stack on the Solstice (where it was Solstice somewhere "in the world"). Possibly the design is a shout-out to [Sol Invictus](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/what-is-the-historical-relationship-between-yule-and-christmas/20706#20706).

---

[image]

Only the most graceful have the balance to wear this one without dropping it.

---

[image][image]

Answer (score 7):

Dwarfs don't mind wearing hats either—er, dwarf planets, I mean.

Below: Pluto trying on some of the History Champion's best hats.

[image: Simply Golden]

Simply Golden!

[image: on fire]

Planet on fire!

[image: eclipse]

Eclpising the Moon...

[image: rainbow]

Flag it, Snap it, Rainbows in the Kuiper Belt!

[image: falling off]

Ai! It's falling off!

[image: yogi]

Plutonic Search

[image: selfies]

Selfies anyone?

[image: trendset]

Just set a trend!

[image: breakfast]

DO BOT DISTURB—EATING BREAKFAST

[image: hats off]

Hats off to Pluto

[image: times eleven]

Times Eleven

[image: gotcha]

Gotcha!

[image: fiery]

North Pole Ablaze

[image: dreidel]

Dreidel to the heart

[image: gold]

Just win a hat

[image: scarf]

The Epiphanic hat

[image: father]

Darth Vader invades

[image: times three]

Champion!

Comment: The "planet on fire" made me LOL. That would be a good icon for "Global Warming"

Answer (score 5):

### [image] Ladies and gentlemen: my collection of hats!

---

[image] [image] [image]

> These particular hats were given to me for vomiting rainbows, wearing a fork on my head, trudging through snow and frightening tourists. Note that only one of them is actually a hat.

---

[image] [image] [image] [image]

> These hats signify the fact that I celebrated both Christmas and Hanukkah, and found two different ways of concealing my secret identity. There is a hidden message in this, but it eludes me.

**Update:**

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

> These hats were evidently given to me because I am spending *way* too much time on StackExchange. (And I never ordered the bacon. Can I send this back and get some toast?)

---

### [image] I would like to thank the academy...

---

Comment: If you don't want your bacon, I could always use extra...

Answer (score 5):

The tastiest "hat" of them all...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm tempted to accept this answer.

Comment: [Nothing beats bacon](http://imgur.com/gallery/5DVmKCn).