# Do I earn reputation for scoring posts on Meta?

Tags: support, reputation, winterbash

Recently I added my answer to [this question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/the-mad-hatters-picture-book?cb=1) on meta, and soon got a score of 8 on it. I don't, however, see that I received any reputation for this post. Does Meta simply not give reputation to scoring posts, or did this *question* not allow for reputation received on answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally meta sites had their own reputation, completely independent of the main site. A lot of people complained about that because it meant high-rep main users might still not even be able to edit on meta.

With the current software version, it appears that they simply removed meta rep altogether. However, its still the case that meta "reputation" actions don't affect your main reputation score. Perhaps the meta rep even still exists, just isn't displayed anywhere.

If you want to know more, [this question on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/why-is-the-meta-reputation-derived-directly-from-the-parent-site) may be of interest. In general, posting-software related questions are probably better researched there anyway. Almost nobody hanging out in this meta site has the ability to do anything whatsoever about the StackExchange posting software system.